# How to save object as string in c#

Tags: c#, string, object

I have an object of student

```
Class Student
{
  public Student()
  {
     name = "xyz";
     roll = 20;
     age = 16;
  }
  string name;
  int roll;
  int age;
}

Class Service
{
  Student student = new Student();
  string s = ???
 // what I have to do for getting string like {"name" : "xyz", "roll" : 20, "age" :16}
}
```

I need the string from the above object.

If i serialize the object I am getting something with escape sequences.

Any help would be greatly appreciable.

Comment: Add a public override ToString() function there you can return a string an you can format that as you want.

Comment: Sounds like you just want JSON. Try `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` in package Json.NET. Otherwise if you're trying to pretty print something, just use a format string with `String.Format`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is a simplified example, use **Vsevolod Goloviznin** answer. It is better.

Just use toString();

```
string s = stuident.toString();
```

Add an overload to toString() in the class to get pretty print. My personal preferece is to output JSON.

```
Class Student
{
  public Student()
  {
     name = "xyz";
     roll = 20;
     age = 16;
  }


  public override string toString(){
     return "{name: " + name + ", roll: " + roll + ", age: " + age + "}";
  }

  string name;
  int roll;
  int age;
}
```

Comment: If I added the same it returns Student

Comment: @Magic-Mouse why don't you just use String.Format? it makes it more readable, yet easy to handle

Comment: @chouaib I assume i was too judgmental or careful. But i figured, if one was not aware of how to override toString. i would make the response as basic as possible, thus just concat strings rather than using potential confusing functions.

Comment: No that doesn't diminish the value of your answer at all, I just feel it is more confusing than simple formatting, tastes are not arguable :) . + for the override part: I myself learnt `String.Format` before I knew what `override` is :) don't prejudge please, here you go+1

Comment: `@override` is a java annotation!

Comment: @dotctor you are right... i have been sitting with java at work for the last 3½ week, got languange confused.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like what you really want is to serialize your object to `JSON`.

This can be easily done with [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library like this:

```
Student student = new Student();
var s = JsonConvert.Serialize(student);
```

If you need this in multiple places you can create an extension method or override the `ToString` method of `Student` class:

```
public class Student
{
     public override string ToString()
     {
          return JsonConvert.Serialize(this);
     }
}
```

Comment: @satishkumarV it's just that double quotes are escaped when representing the string in C#. If you write this into file, the slashes will be gone

Answer (score 4):

You have to serialize your object. For example with the JavaScriptSerializer:

```
string s = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(student);
```

Don't forget to add the following using

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

Answer (score 2):

Override the ToString() method of your Student class

something like

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("Name: {0}, Roll: {1}, Age: {2}", name, roll, age);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The string in your example is JSON. You can use http://www.newtonsoft.com/jsont
to serialize:
    string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(student);

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to serialize it to JSON, check out http://www.newtonsoft.com/json and use it to call `string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(student);`